# how to search record with multiple input

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search record with multiple input.If i enter keyword like delhi,mumbai in text field
record should be display

```
my code is
<input type="search" name="search[]">
$location=$_POST['search'];
mysql_query("select * from record where location like '%$location%'")
```

please help me i am not able to search record with multiple location

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
2. I assume you have multiple input fields named "search[]".

What you should do is something like this:

```
$locations=$_POST['search'];
$likeSqlStr = '';
foreach ($locations as $loc) {
   if (!empty($loc)) {
      $likeSqlStr .= " OR location LIKE '%" . $loc . "%'"; 
   }
}
$query = "select * from record where (" . (!empty($likeSqlStr) ? '0' . $likeSqlStr : '1') . ")";
$results = mysqli_query($query);
```